# Dynamically change text in table using by clicking a checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have a data in JSON format and I convert it to a HTML `table`. Now I want to 
change the text from `False` to `True` if I check the checkbox. How can I do that?

Here is the code for creating the HTML table:

```
$.each(result, function (index, value) { 
  var Data = "<tr>" +
    "<td class='' id='stdID' >" + value.StudentID + "</td>" +
    "<td class='' id='stdRol'>" + value.RollNo + "</td>" +
    "<td class='' id='stdName'>" + value.FirstName + "</td>" +
    "<td class='cbx' value='1'><input  type='checkbox' id='cc"+index+"'><span id='checkbox-value'> False</span></td>" +
    "</tr>";
  SetData.append(Data);
```

This is the result of this: [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPxDH.png)

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what you require you need to use a delegated event handler, as you dynamically append the rows after the page has loaded, to hook to the `change` event of the checkboxes. Then you can set the text of the sibling `span` element based on the `checked` property. Something like this:

```js
$('table').on('change', ':checkbox', function() {
  $(this).next('span').text(this.checked);
});
```

```css
span.checkbox-value { text-transform: capitalize; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="stdID">value.StudentID</td>
    <td class="stdRol">value.RollNo</td>
    <td class="stdName">value.FirstName</td>
    <td class="cbx" value="1">
      <input type="checkbox" id="cc1">
      <span class="checkbox-value">False</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="stdID">value.StudentID</td>
    <td class="stdRol">value.RollNo</td>
    <td class="stdName">value.FirstName</td>
    <td class="cbx" value="1">
      <input type="checkbox" id="cc2">
      <span class="checkbox-value">False</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You should note that your loop is creating multiple elements which have the same `id`, which is invalid HTML. In the example above I've changed them to classes instead.

Comment: Thank so much Dear

Comment: plz tell where i put this code 
  span.checkbox - value { text - transform: capitalize; }

Comment: That goes in your CSS stylesheet

Comment: Don't forget to accept answers if they helped. That goes for all your previous questions too.

Comment: Thank its Work for me

Answer (score 0):

Another way around to achieve your desired output

```js
$(document).on('change', '.changeStatus', function() {
  var row = $(this).closest('tr');
  if($(this). prop("checked") == true){
    row.find('.changeValue').html('True');
  } else {
   row.find('.changeValue').html('False');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>Roll_no</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="changeStatus"></td>
      <td class="changeValue">False</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>Roll_no</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="changeStatus"></td>
      <td class="changeValue">False</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>Roll_no</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="changeStatus"></td>
      <td class="changeValue">False</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```